# Convertion on List<SelectedItems> to List <String> in java bean

Tags: java, jsf, type-conversion

I have an ArrayList named as AddressList and I want to convert it to an ArrayList .I have tried the below

In addressbean

```
     private String addressSelected;    
 private List<SelectItem> addresslList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
```

I got the exception when i called the below to fetch the addressList1 from DB

```
addresslList = GenerateAddressDAO.getAddressList();
```

getAddressList() method has query to fetch the address details and return a `list<String>`  addresslist1

In UI

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{addressbean.addressSelected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.addresslList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But It throws the below exception
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument Error: An option for component AddressList was not an instance of javax.faces.model.SelectItem.  Type found: java.util.ArrayList."